# docker installation fails on raspberry pi 1b because containerd service crashed

Tags: linux, docker, raspberry-pi

I dusted off an old Raspberry Pi 1B (512 MB RAM) and want to use it for some educational projects with docker.

I installed the latest Raspberry Pi OS 32bit Lite on an 32 GB card, updated the installation and tried to install docker based on the installation guideline from the docker website.

The installation fails because `containerd.service` crashes. The installation log looks like this:

```
pi@pi1:~ $ sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apparmor dbus-user-session docker-ce-rootless-extras git git-man liberror-perl libltdl7 libslirp0 slirp4netns
Suggested packages:
  apparmor-profiles-extra apparmor-utils cgroupfs-mount | cgroup-lite git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc
  git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apparmor containerd.io dbus-user-session docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-compose-plugin
  git git-man liberror-perl libltdl7 libslirp0 slirp4netns
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 94.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 386 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/raspbian/raspbian bullseye/main armhf apparmor armhf 2.13.6-10 [532 kB]
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf dbus-user-session armhf 1.12.24-0+deb11u1 [99.7 kB]
Get:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye/stable armhf containerd.io armhf 1.6.15-1 [20.4 MB]
Get:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf libslirp0 armhf 4.4.0-1+deb11u2 [50.2 kB]
Get:6 http://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/raspbian/raspbian bullseye/main armhf libltdl7 armhf 2.4.6-15 [388 kB]
Get:5 http://mirror1.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/archive.raspbian.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf git armhf 1:2.30.2-1 [4,724 kB]
Get:4 http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/raspbian/raspbian bullseye/main armhf git-man all 1:2.30.2-1 [1,827 kB]
Get:8 http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/raspbian/raspbian bullseye/main armhf slirp4netns armhf 1.0.1-2 [29.0 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.pyratelan.org/raspbian/raspbian bullseye/main armhf liberror-perl all 0.17029-1 [31.0 kB]
Get:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye/stable armhf docker-ce-cli armhf 5:20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye [37.5 MB]
Get:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye/stable armhf docker-ce armhf 5:20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye [13.1 MB]
Get:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye/stable armhf docker-ce-rootless-extras armhf 5:20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye [7,442 kB]
Get:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye/stable armhf docker-compose-plugin armhf 2.14.1~debian-bullseye [8,218 kB]
Fetched 94.3 MB in 1min 17s (1,218 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package apparmor.
(Reading database ... 43694 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-apparmor_2.13.6-10_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking apparmor (2.13.6-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package containerd.io.
Preparing to unpack .../01-containerd.io_1.6.15-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking containerd.io (1.6.15-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dbus-user-session.
Preparing to unpack .../02-dbus-user-session_1.12.24-0+deb11u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking dbus-user-session (1.12.24-0+deb11u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../03-docker-ce-cli_5%3a20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce-cli (5:20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce.
Preparing to unpack .../04-docker-ce_5%3a20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce (5:20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce-rootless-extras.
Preparing to unpack .../05-docker-ce-rootless-extras_5%3a20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-compose-plugin.
Preparing to unpack .../06-docker-compose-plugin_2.14.1~debian-bullseye_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking docker-compose-plugin (2.14.1~debian-bullseye) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../07-liberror-perl_0.17029-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17029-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git-man.
Preparing to unpack .../08-git-man_1%3a2.30.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.30.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git.
Preparing to unpack .../09-git_1%3a2.30.2-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.30.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libltdl7:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libltdl7_2.4.6-15_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libltdl7:armhf (2.4.6-15) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libslirp0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libslirp0_4.4.0-1+deb11u2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libslirp0:armhf (4.4.0-1+deb11u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package slirp4netns.
Preparing to unpack .../12-slirp4netns_1.0.1-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking slirp4netns (1.0.1-2) ...
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17029-1) ...
Setting up apparmor (2.13.6-10) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/apparmor.service → /lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service.
Setting up dbus-user-session (1.12.24-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up containerd.io (1.6.15-1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/containerd.service → /lib/systemd/system/containerd.service.
Job for containerd.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered causing the control process to dump core.
See "systemctl status containerd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Setting up docker-compose-plugin (2.14.1~debian-bullseye) ...
Setting up libltdl7:armhf (2.4.6-15) ...
Setting up docker-ce-cli (5:20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye) ...
Setting up libslirp0:armhf (4.4.0-1+deb11u2) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.30.2-1) ...
Setting up docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye) ...
Setting up slirp4netns (1.0.1-2) ...
Setting up docker-ce (5:20.10.22~3-0~debian-bullseye) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service → /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket → /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket.
A dependency job for docker.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com

Jan 14 18:29:28 pi1 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
Jan 14 18:29:28 pi1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up git (1:2.30.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

But the log of the service is also not helpful, just says SEGV:

```
pi@pi1:~ $ systemctl status containerd.service
● containerd.service - containerd container runtime
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: core-dump) since Sat 2023-01-14 21:40:06 CET; 2s ago
       Docs: https://containerd.io
    Process: 21854 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe overlay (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 21855 ExecStart=/usr/bin/containerd (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
   Main PID: 21855 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
        CPU: 602ms

Jan 14 21:40:06 pi1 systemd[1]: Failed to start containerd container runtime.
pi@pi1:~ $ journalctl -xe
Jan 14 22:20:19 pi1 systemd[1]: Stopped containerd container runtime.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit containerd.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit containerd.service has finished.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4073 and the job result is done.
Jan 14 22:20:19 pi1 systemd[1]: Starting containerd container runtime...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit containerd.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit containerd.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4073.
Jan 14 22:20:20 pi1 systemd[1]: containerd.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit containerd.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'dumped' and its exit status is 11.
Jan 14 22:20:20 pi1 systemd[1]: containerd.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ The unit containerd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'core-dump'.
Jan 14 22:20:20 pi1 systemd[1]: Failed to start containerd container runtime.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit containerd.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit containerd.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4073 and the job result is failed.
```

I tried a reboot (which was recommended in other questions where this issue appeared *after* a successful installation), but the issue remains.

I used the exact same OS image (Raspi OS Lite 32 bit) and installation commands to set up docker on a Raspi 2B, which works flawlessly. And I tried the regular Raspi OS 32 bit (with desktop), but the same error. So it must have something to do with the Raspi 1B. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and using [the convenience script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-convenience-script) for installation worked for me.

The documentation also mentions that the repository installation is not supported for Raspbian, but I had overlooked it at first.